# Dropdown replacement - submit does not work

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, replace

I tried to reuse a dropdown replacement found on internet but I encountered two problems:

1) I would like the replacement to make a submit instead of creating a href. I tried to rewrite the function and added onChange in the -tag but it didn't work. Does anybody has a hint?

2) I tried to add flags and expanded the function with `'<img class="option[selected]" />' +`  and added two css-classes with the names of the values and the URLs of the images, but as I am a Javascript newbie I can't find a working solution.

Here is the whole function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    createDropDown();

    $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
       $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
     });

    $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
       var $clicked = $(e.target);
       if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
       $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
    });

    $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
      var text = $(this).html();
      $(".dropdown dt a").html(text);
      $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();

      var langForm_mylang = $("#langForm_mylang");
      langForm_mylang.val($(this).find("span.value").html())
      });
     });

function createDropDown(){
  var langForm_mylang = $("#langForm_mylang");
  var selected = langForm_mylang.find("option[selected]");
  var options = $("option", langForm_mylang);

  $("#langFormReplacement").append('<dl id="target" class="dropdown"></dl>')
  $("#target").append('<dt><a href="#">' + selected.text() + 
      '<img class="$langCode" />' +
      '<span class="value">' + selected.val() + 
      '</span></a></dt>')
  $("#target").append('<dd><ul></ul></dd>')

  options.each(function(){
     $("#target dd ul").append('<li><a href="#">' + 
       $(this).text() + '<span class="value">' + 
       $(this).val() + '</span></a></li>');
  });
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to create a fiddle? Maybe you'll receive much faster answers.

Comment: jQuerybeast is not trying to be mean, but if you want free answers it makes sense to give as clear a picture of your code as possible. Programming is abstract by definition so anything that makes it easier helps people understand your problem. JSFiddle.net really helps with that.

Comment: I found the solution: a line of code more was necessary below createDropdown (); $("#langForm_mylang").change(function() {